# Javascript - Disable a control when a drop down list selected index changed

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I need to know how to disable a button when the selected index of a drop down list has changed. I want to do it in javascript because i don't want to cause a postback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this JavaScript function (it assumes your button has a `my-button` id):

```
function disableButton()
{
  button = document.getElementById("my-button");
  button.disabled = true;
}
```

In order to respond of the change of the selected index, add this [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp) event to the dropdown: `onchange="disableButton()"`

**Edit**: For more information about the disabled property go to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_disabled.asp), they have lots of information about [JavaScript and the HTML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/).